# jquery anchor effect does not work properly

Tags: menus, jquery, urls

I have the following script that provides an anchor effect:

```
// Smooth scrolling when clicking on a hash link
    $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        if ($(window).width() > 1023) {
            var $scrollTop = $target.offset().top - 120;
        } else {
            var $scrollTop = $target.offset().top;
        }

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $scrollTop
        }, 900, 'swing');
    });
```

The problem is that this only works on home page, but in the other pages it does not work because I need to provide the web link (www.url.com/#anchor). But if I do this, the effect does not apply. someone knows how to add to the effect, for example `get_site_url ('/#anchor/');` , and so this always take the url of the web as a base?

I hope I have expressed myself well.
Greetings and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS now has the property `scroll-behavior` (browser support is there [but not so great](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior)). You can use it as [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#Accessibility_concerns):

> ```
> html {
>   scroll-behavior: smooth;
> }
>
> @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
>   html {
>     scroll-behavior: auto;
>   }
> }
> ```

If this doesn't work for you, you're stuck with JS. The problem is, on a new page load, browsers automatically jump to the position of the fragment. But there is a workaround as [described in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30293936):

> ```
> // to top right away
> if (window.location.hash) scroll(0,0);
> // void some browsers issue
> setTimeout(function() { scroll(0,0); }, 1);
>
> $(function() {
>     // *only* if we have anchor on the url
>     if(window.location.hash) {
>         // smooth scroll to the anchor id
>         $('html, body').animate({
>             scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top + 'px'
>         }, 1000, 'swing');
>     }
>
> });
> ```

Comment: Wow, The CSS option works perfectly. One more question, is the first time I use an anchor effect and now the problem is that it slides under the title because I have a sticky menu, how could I fix this bug? Thank you

Comment: @DarioB. You can do this in JS, but there is also a pure CSS way: [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target). The WordPress Docs [uses this mechanism](https://make.wordpress.org/docs/handbook/get-involved/#what-can-i-do), just inspect the headline and you'll see `padding-top` and negative `margin-top`